# chained java.util.function.Predicate call to compare predicates

Tags: java-8, java-stream, predicate

I'm trying to get this working :

```
Predicate<Integer> predicateInteger = i ->  i>0;
System.out.println(predicateInteger.test(1)); // works and prints true
```

Now I'm trying to define another predicate like on `predicateInteger` using equals :

```
// stmt below DOES NOT COMPILE : Target type of a lambda conversion must be an interface

Predicate<Integer> predicateEq = predicateInteger.equals(i -> new Boolean(true));
System.out.println(predicateEq.test(8));// I want this to print "TRUE" on equals .
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your requirement. `i > 0` is itself a predicate and would return `true` or `false` when `test`ed. Even if java allowed you to continue with the second statement, it still won't make any sense because `if(something.equals(true))` is the same as `if(something)`.

Comment: Nothing in this question makes sense. You are not chaining predicates and “to print "TRUE" on equals” is incomprehensible. What means “on equals” in the context of a statement calling `test` and why should it print the string `"TRUE"` when nothing in this code ever referred to that string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how predicates and functional interfaces (lambda expressions) in general. The `Predicate` class has the only method `boolean test(T t)`. The lambda expression is nothing different from an anonymous class implementation. Notice there is **no** `equals` method, therefore the lambda expressions are not comparable (in terms of equality).

```
Predicate<Integer> predicateInteger = i -> i > 0;
```

```
Predicate<Integer> predicateInteger = new Predicate<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Integer i) {
        return i > 0;
    }
}
```

Actually, the `Predicate#test` returns `boolean` which can be directly printed out:

```
Predicate<Integer> integerPredicate = i -> i > 0;
System.out.println(integerPredicate.test(8));                                  // true
```

Seems you want to *compare* the result value to something else, defined with another `Predicate`.

```
Predicate<Integer> integerPredicate = i -> i > 0;
Predicate<Object> resultPredicate = i -> true;

boolean result = integerPredicate.test(8) == resultPredicate.test("whatever");
System.out.println(result);                                                    // true
```

Note that, in fact, `Predicate<Object> predicate = i -> true` is practically a `Supplier` which returns a constant value regardless the input (actually, it has *no* input).

```
Predicate<Integer> integerPredicate = i -> i > 0;
Supplier<Boolean> resultSupplier = () -> true;

boolean result = integerPredicate.test(8) == resultSupplier.get();
System.out.println(result);                                                    // true
```

However, this makes *no sense* as long as the `integerPredicate` can be printed out directly with no `resultSupplier`.

```
Predicate<Integer> integerPredicate = i -> i > 0;
System.out.println(integerPredicate.test(8));                                  // true
```

... and we are back at the beginning.

---

The last thing that comes to my mind is to print out the result always on the method `test` call. All you need is to define a decorator, that wraps the `Predicate` delegate and submits an action on the `test` method call using `Consumer<Boolean` where `Boolean` is the former predicate's result.

```
@AllArgsConstructor // constructor omitted (Lombok) for sake of brevity
public class CallbackPredicate<T> implements Predicate<T> {

    private final Predicate<T> delegate;
    private final Consumer<Boolean> callback;

    @Override
    public final boolean test(final T t) {
        boolean result = delegate.test(t);
        callback.accept(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
Predicate<Integer> integerPredicate = new CallbackPredicate<>(
        i -> i > 0,                                              // Predicate<Integer>
        System.out::println);                                    // Callback

integerPredicate.test(8);                                        // prints true
```

---

The predicates can be also chained using the `AND` clause represented by the `Predicate#and` method:

```
Predicate<Integer> largerThanZero = i -> i > 0;
Predicate<Integer> smallerThanSix = i -> i < 6;

Predicate<Integer> betweenZeroAndSix = largerThanZero.and(smallerThanSix);

System.out.println(betweenZeroAndSix.test(-5));                  // false
System.out.println(betweenZeroAndSix.test(5));                   // true
System.out.println(betweenZeroAndSix.test(15));                  // false
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this great explanation. It really is helpful !. However, I was trying to compare outcome of two Predicates, should this be a right way as well :` Predicate<Integer> predicateInteger = i ->  i>0; ` -> that the first predicate , and then : Predicate<Integer> predicateEq = predicateInteger.and(i -> i<6); -> the second predicate , and ` System.out.println(predicateEq.test(5));`// prints true

Comment: Check my edit. I think you have enough material to know how predicates (and other functional interfaces) work.

Comment: Nice answer @NikolasCharalambidis ;)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me achieve what I want :

```
// when this is the first predicate:
Predicate<Integer> predicateInteger = i ->  i>0;  
// and when this second predicate compares with the first, 
Predicate<Integer> predicateEq = predicateInteger.and(i -> i<6); 
// then :
System.out.println(predicateEq.test(5));// prints true
```